# C# Remove duplicate child/grandchild/greatgrandchild nodes in a treeview

Tags: c#, treeview

I have a treeview which is generated dynamically. My issue is that it adds same nodes -it receives the list from another application though wherein the same item is repeated, but i do not want to include the repeated items in my treeview. I have tried to avoid adding the node at the first case; but failed. My code to check if exists is below( tried some):

```
if(treeViewLeft.Nodes[0].Nodes[index1].Nodes[index2].Nodes.Find(childnode.Name,true).Length>0)
 { 
treeViewLeft.Nodes[0].Nodes[index1].Nodes[index2].Nodes.Add(childnode); 
 }
```

and

```
if(treeViewLeft.Nodes[0].Nodes[index1].Nodes[index2].Nodes.Contains(childnode.Name))
 { 
treeViewLeft.Nodes[0].Nodes[index1].Nodes[index2].Nodes.Add(childnode); 
 }
```

Comment: If you can't stop them from being added then they probably aren't duplicates.  Nodes with same names at different levels of hierarchy are not considered duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be that as you are creating child nodes, they are technically different objects even though all of their properties are the same.  So node.Contains(childnode) won't return true in this case.

You can instead add a function to loop through all the name properties on a node looking for a match:

```cs
public bool CheckNameExists(TreeNode parent, string text)
{
    foreach (TreeNode item in parent.Nodes)
    {
        if (item.Name == text) return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

So then I would take your second example and change it to this:

```cs
if(CheckNameExists(treeViewLeft.Nodes[0].Nodes[index1].Nodes[index2], childnode.Name) == false)
{ 
    treeViewLeft.Nodes[0].Nodes[index1].Nodes[index2].Nodes.Add(childnode); 
}
```